# Unable to install R package "XML"

Tags: r

I cannot install the XML package on my rstudio. I use anaconda. Below is the log when I try to install:

> install.packages("XML") trying URL
>   'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/XML_3.98-1.11.tar.gz' Content
>   type 'application/x-gzip' length 1599537 bytes (1.5 MB)
>   ================================================== downloaded 1.5 MB
>
> - installing *source* package ‘XML’ ...
>     ** package ‘XML’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked checking for gcc... x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang checking for C compiler
>     default output file name...  configure: error: C compiler cannot
>     create executables See `config.log' for more details. ERROR:
>     configuration failed for package ‘XML’
> - removing ‘/Users/Anton/anaconda3/lib/R/library/XML’ Warning in install.packages :   installation of package ‘XML’ had non-zero exit
>     status
>
> The downloaded source packages are in
>     ‘/private/var/folders/jw/4ff5f8y91h3g0973h3s7zr9h0000gn/T/RtmpRfb8mV/downloaded_packages’
>   Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library' Making 'packages.html'
>   ... done

Any ideas?

Comment: In my experience with R, this sort of problem is usually due to versioning, e.g. your R version is too old/new for the package, or some of the dependencies which `XML` references are also out of date.

Comment: I'm running 3.4.3. I can't update 3.4.4 on Anaconda (unless maybe I mess around with linkers). Is 3.4.3 a problem?